# Best Way to make an SQL time of service query

Tags: mysql, time, between

Best Way to make an SQL time of service query

I'm looking to do a query like

`select * from table where HOUR(NOW()) between OpenHour and CloseHour;`

But I have to take in mind that some places had an OpenHour higher than CloseHour, like NigthClubs....

Comment: why don't you compare between datetime values?

Comment: select * from table where datetime(now()) between OpenHour and CloseHour;?  Openhour antes closehour are both time type...

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that openhour and closehour are integers, as implied by the use of `HOUR(NOW())`:

```
WHERE (    closehour   > openhour
       AND HOUR(NOW()) > openhour
       AND HOUR(NOW()) < closehour)
   OR (    closehour   < openhour
       AND HOUR(NOW()) < openhour
       AND HOUR(NOW()) > closehour)
   OR (    closehour   = openhour)
```

(That last `OR` clause tests for "open 24 hours.")

If you were using `TIME` instead of `INT` you would have to replace the subexpressions `X <rel> Y` with `TIMEDIFF(X, Y) <rel> 0`.